# Properties of function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

The relation $R$, which belongs to $S\times S$, is an equivalence relation.
Let $R_{1} = (S\times S)\backslash R$.  I need 6 properties of this relation $R_{1}$. I know how to check them, but I can't understand how the relations between these functions. In mathematical form I mean. What are in relation with what?

Comment: Let $S = \{a, b, c\}$. Make up an equivalence relation, say the one that has the property: $a \sim b$ and $b \not \sim c$. Then draw $S \times S ?
 R$.  Try to draw a function from $S$ into this. Try doing this for bigger examples and try to see what is going on, if it doesn't click.

Comment: It's symmetric, non-transitive, and irreflexive, for one.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you have a relation $R\subseteq S\times S$, where R is a relation between two ordered pairs in   $S\times S$.  So then another relation $R_1 = R^c = S\times S \setminus S$.   So, we know that R is an equivalence relation, and we are trying to find six properties of $R_1$, the set of ordered pairs from $S\times S$ that are **not in** R.

Comment: $R_1$  is not reflexive, because for all $a\in S$, $(a, a) \in R$ (because R is any equivalence relation, it is reflexive), hence, there are no elements of the form $(a, a) \in R_1$. So $R_1$ is not reflexive, but is, indeed, irreflexive.